# GNU AS value not in assigned section

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, gnu-assembler, linker-scripts

I am currently trying to build a two-stage bootloader in GNU assembler. I use the `as` command to compile the assembly files and the `ld` command to link them to the final binary. Some information beforehand:

```
$ as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28 [...]
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-linux-gnu'
```

And `ld`:

```
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.28 [...]
```

The affected assembly file:

```
.code16

.section .test

label: .short 0x1234

.section .text

    .global _setup32

_setup32:
    cli

    xor %ax, %ax

    # Some more code [...]
```

And the linker script used to build the binary file: Before anyone asks, the following linker script is the stage-2 part of my bootloader, hence the origin of `0x8000`.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
ENTRY(_setup32)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x8000;
    _SETUP_START = .;

    .test ALIGN(0x10) : {
        *(.test*)
    }

    .text ALIGN(0x10) : {
        _TEXT_START = .;
        *(.text*)
        _TEXT_END = .;
    }

    .rodata ALIGN(0x10) : {
        _RODATA_START = .;
        *(.rodata*)
        _RODATA_END = .;
    }

    .data ALIGN(0x10) : {
        _DATA_START = .;
        *(.data*)
        _DATA_END = .;
    }

    .bss ALIGN(0x10) : {
        _BSS_START = .;
        *(.bss*)
        _BSS_END = .;
    }

    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment*)
    }

    _SETUP_END = .;
}
```

However, after the final `setup.bin` file has been built, the value `0x1234` is not located at the beginning of the hexdump. In fact, it is not even included in the final built. The bootloader is working absolutely fine, I'm just unable to assign variables or in general, bytes to individual sections.

I am using the following, very basic rules in my Makefile:

```
$(SETUPBIN): $(SETUP).o
    $(LD) -T setup.ld $(SETUP).o -o $@

%.o: %.asm
    $(AS) $< -o $@
```

Furthermore: I know about GNU AS directives `.text` and `.data`, but they only store the instructions and bytes in fixed locations of the binary: Everything in the `.text` directive is located at the beginning of the binary whereas everything in `.data` is found at the end of the binary.

How do I put everything in a custom section?

Comment: x86 is little-endian.  You did check for the byte sequence `0x34  0x12`, right?  I'm not sure if you need to do anything special beyond that linker script to make a custom section appear in the output binary.  (e.g. for ELF output you need an `"@progbits"` attribute to get a section placed in a segment that will be mapped, but in a flat binary all the sections except .bss are just in the binary.)

Comment: @PeterCordes correct. But said value is not found anywhere in the flat binary. I too wondered if its just for flat binaries that the output is somewhat cropped or optimized away, but I haven't found anything about that either.

Comment: You need to use `.section .test, "a"` to mark it allocatable.

Comment: @Jester thanks a lot, that worked perfectly!